# How to make combination of two columns as a unique key?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('edition', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('volume');
        $table->text('cover')->nullable();
        $table->enum('number', ['1', '2']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('journal', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('id_edition')->references('id')->on('edition')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

I wanted to make the combination of column Volume and Number as a unique key. For example, there is a data "Volume 1, Number 1" and when user insert the same combination it will throw an error message that the data already exist. Is there a way I can do this in Laravel ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just include the following snippet inside the `up()` method

```
$table->unique(['volume','number']);
```

By having this constraint set, if you insert 'Volume 1 , Number 1` once it'll be fine. However, if you try to do the same again, it'll throw an error.

Conditions:

1. You are using some good DBMS, such as `MySQL` and not `SQLITE`
2. You successfully migrated this change into the database.

Comment: with this do I can still insert the same Volume data with different number ? Because my data will looks pretty much like this : "Volume 1, Number 1" and "Volume 1, Number 2", "Volume 2, Number 1", "Volume 2, Number 2" .. One volume can have two different numbers

Comment: If so, then how is the rules would look like ?

Comment: You mean the rules in model?

Comment: In request, and also model if possible :)

Comment: This `unique key` is implemented at database level, hence `Laravel` won't know it until you yourself ask for it and then compare. For example, you can query the database for a record having certain `volume & number` if any record is returned, that means it is duplicate.

Comment: However have a look at this(https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-check-for-unique-column-combanation-from-the-validation-rule)

Comment: Okay, gonna try this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [uniquewith-validator](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) package that allows you to validate a unique combination of fields like this

```
'field1' => 'required|unique_with:table_name,field2'
```

The above code will check if the combination of field1 and field2 is unique in the table with the given table_name.